# Pandas force NaN to bottom of each column at each index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where multiple rows span each index.  Taking the first index, for example, has such a structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "first", 1.0, 1.0, np.NaN],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, 2.0, np.NaN, 2.0],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 3.0, 3.0]],
            columns=["ID", "Name", "val1", "val2", "val3"],
            index=[0, 0, 0])

Out[4]:
    ID   Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A  first     1     1   NaN
0  NaN    NaN     2   NaN     2
0  NaN    NaN   NaN     3     3
```

I would like to sort/order each column such that the `NaN`s are at the bottom of each column at that given index - a result which looks like this:

```
    ID   Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A  first     1     1     2
0  NaN    NaN     2     3     3
0  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
```

A more explicit example might look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "first", 1.0, 1.0, np.NaN],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, 2.0, np.NaN, 2.0],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 3.0, 3.0],
            ["B", "second", 4.0, 4.0, np.NaN],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, 5.0, np.NaN, 5.0],
            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6.0, 6.0]],
            columns=[ "ID", "Name", "val1", "val2", "val3"],
            index=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

Out[5]:
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1   NaN
0  NaN     NaN     2   NaN     2
0  NaN     NaN   NaN     3     3
1    B  second     4     4   NaN
1  NaN     NaN     5   NaN     5
1  NaN     NaN   NaN     6     6
```

with the desired result to look like this:

```
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1     2
0  NaN     NaN     2     3     3
0  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    B  second     4     4     5
1  NaN     NaN     5     6     6
1  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I have many thousands of rows in this dataframe, with each index containing up to a few hundred rows.  My desired result will be very helpful when I `to_csv` the dataframe.

I have attempted to use `sort_values(['val1','val2','val3'])` on the whole data frame, but this results in the indices becoming disordered.  I have tried to iterate through each index and sort in place, but this too does not restrict the `NaN` to the bottom of each indices' column.  I have also tried to `fillna` to another value, such as 0, but I have not been successful here, either.

While I am certainly using it wrong, the `na_position` parameter in `sort_values` does not produce the desired outcome, though it seems this is likely what want.

Edit:

The final df's index is not required to be in numerical order as in my second example.

By changing `ignore_index` to `False` in the single line of @Leb's third code block,

```
pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

to

```
pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

and by creating a temp df for all rows in a given index, I was able to make this work - not pretty, but it orders things how I need them. If someone (certainly) has a better way, please let me know.

```
new_df = df.ix[0]
new_df = pd.concat([new_df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in new_df], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
max_index = df.index[-1]
for i in range(1, max_index + 1):
    tmp = df.ix[i]
    tmp = pd.concat([tmp[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in tmp], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df,tmp])


In [10]: new_df
Out[10]:
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1     2
1  NaN     NaN     2     3     3
2  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
0    B  second     4     4     5
1  NaN     NaN     5     6     6
2  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the issue of pushing nans to an edge has been discussed on github.  For your particular frame, I'd probably do it manually at the Python level, and not worry about performance much.  Something like

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).transform(lambda x: sorted(x,key=pd.isnull))
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1     2
0  NaN     NaN     2     3     3
0  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    B  second     4     4     5
1  NaN     NaN     5     6     6
1  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

should work.  Note that since `sorted` is a stable sort, and we're using `pd.isnull` as the key (where False < True), we push the NaNs to the end while preserving the order of the remaining objects.  Also note that here I'm grouping just on the index; we could alternatively have grouped on whatever we wanted.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer cos it looks like a small cranky kid against this. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Given df:

```
pd.DataFrame([["A","first",1.0,1.0,np.NaN],
            [np.NaN,np.NaN,2.0,np.NaN,2.0],
            [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3.0,3.0]],
            columns=[ "ID",    "Name",    "val1",    "val2",    "val3"],index=[0,1,2])
```

I changed index to make sure order stays.

```
df
Out[127]: 
    ID   Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A  first     1     1   NaN
1  NaN    NaN     2   NaN     2
2  NaN    NaN   NaN     3     3
```

Using:

```
pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Will give:

```
Out[130]: 
     0      1   2   3   4
0    A  first   1   1   2
1  NaN    NaN   2   3   3
2  NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Same for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","first",1.0,1.0,np.NaN],
            [np.NaN,np.NaN,2.0,np.NaN,2.0],
            [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3.0,3.0],
            ["B","second",4.0,4.0,np.NaN],
            [np.NaN,np.NaN,5.0,np.NaN,5.0],
             [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,6.0,6.0]],
            columns=[ "ID",    "Name",    "val1",    "val2",    "val3"],index=[0,0,0,1,1,1])

df
Out[132]: 
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1   NaN
0  NaN     NaN     2   NaN     2
0  NaN     NaN   NaN     3     3
1    B  second     4     4   NaN
1  NaN     NaN     5   NaN     5
1  NaN     NaN   NaN     6     6

pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
Out[133]: 
     0       1   2   3   4
0    A   first   1   1   2
1    B  second   2   3   3
2  NaN     NaN   4   4   5
3  NaN     NaN   5   6   6
4  NaN     NaN NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN     NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

<strike>**After additional comments**</strike>

```
new = pd.concat([df[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df.iloc[:,2:]], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new.index = df.index
cols = df.iloc[:,2:].columns
new.columns = cols
df.drop(cols,inplace=True,axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df,new],axis=1)

df
Out[37]: 
    ID    Name  val1  val2  val3
0    A   first     1     1     2
0  NaN     NaN     2     3     3
0  NaN     NaN     4     4     5
1    B  second     5     6     6
1  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This sorts the entire column, it doesn't just sends the NaN's to the bottom, though, so it can scramble the order of the not-NaN values, right?

Comment: Yes, but `NaN` values are already scrambled throughout the whole dataframe. You can't just move them to the bottom and keep the index of other values. If the `NaN`s were grouped then it is possible.

Comment: I think you *can* do it if you're willing to do enough shenanigans. You could, for example, for each column: copy the series; count the `NaN`s; strip the `NaN`s keeping the values in order, append the same number of `NaN`s at the end. Then, create a new dataframe with these adulterated series as columns. It's not what @AGS asked, though, I was just thinking about the possibility

Comment: I thought you were referring to the index values being scrambled. Yes the way you describe it can be done, go for it ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Leb.  This answer gets me closer, however, columns 'ID' and 'Name' need to keep their original spacing between each index.

Comment: @AGS, are you trying to keep those columns `NaN`? Or are you using `fillna`?

Comment: In my non-toy version, the only `NaN`s I get rid of are those that satisfy `dropna(how='all',inplace=True)`, e.g. rows composed of all `NaN`.  The rest I keep in place for proper spacing in a .csv document.

Comment: @AGS, just saw your edit, I'll look into it some more

Answer (score 1):

```
In [219]:
df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x : x.sort(na_position = 'last' , inplace = False))
Out[219]:
    ID  Name    val1    val2    val3
0   A   first      1    1       2
0   NaN NaN        2    3       3
0   NaN NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN
1   B   second      4   4       5
1   NaN NaN         5   6       6
1   NaN NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: The reason that I didn't use this but dropped down to the Python level is because it sorts the *non*-NaN values as well.

Comment: Say that val1 contained the numbers 1,2,6,5 instead of 1,2,4,5 as it does now.  Your approach won't just push the NaNs to the end, it will turn 6,5 into 5,6.